# javascript variable always is type of string ,even i make it as number

Tags: javascript, string, variables, numbers, initialization

Hi I have the following code, even if I want to make the variable number, the       type is still string, any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

```
  var status = 100
  alert(status) 
  alert(typeof(status)) gives string
```

Comment: Just tried and it shows up as a string in FF and Chrome, but as a number in IE-11.

Comment: Confirmed answer in duplicate question. If you change the name to something other than status the typeof returns as "number" in FF, IE, and Chrome.